# ReactDOM.render but using a class

Tags: reactjs

I need some help, is there a way to get
ReactDOM.render to "write " using a class name rather that a div id

```
    <div class=divclass>xxx</div>
    <div id="react-target">
        <p>
            React should start working in a few milli seconds
        </p>
        <p>
            If you can see this, React is not working right.
        </p>
    </div>

<script>
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test1'), document.getElementById('react-target'));
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test2'), .divclass);
</script>
```

Comment: You could use `document.querySelector('.my-class')`.

Comment: Why you need to do this, you can have another `id` and target that `id`. Using `class` will create conflict if the document contains multiple classes with same name. You need to target correct class every time.

Comment: hi ravibagul this is a preexisting code i am modifyig

Comment: Whoops sorry modifying (sorry for the spelling mistake)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Ans** : **Yes** you can use the `class`  inside the render method.

But you cannot use the way you are using it right now , I.e you first need to select the div you are targeting by `getElementsByClassName`.

Keep in mind that the `getElementsByClassName` returns a list of DOM elements so you need to access the right `div` by indexing it properly `[ pos ]` unlike the `getElementById` which returns the DOM element itself.

```
    <script>
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test1'),document.getElementById('react-target')); 
 ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test2'), document.getElementsByClassName('divclass')[0]; 

     </script>
```

Comment: wooohooo that worked , modified it a bit :)          ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test1'),document.getElementById('react-target')); 
            ReactDOM.render(React.createElement('div', null, 'test2'), document.getElementsByClassName('divclass')[0]);